# The iOS app cannot be installed due to developer certificate issues

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, itunes-app

We are using test flight build for submitting apps on IOS itunes server.
some days back it was working fine but now after submission from Xcode
we are getting below error:-

Error Details~
Could not install 
The app could not be installed because the developer's certificate is no longer valid.

I have not much knowledge about it, as per browsing through forums may be someone revoked the certs,because the provision profile is also invalid, my question is from where i can find new development certificate (may be a p12 file ) ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can always create new certificates in the Dev Portal.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new certificates and provisioning profiles from Apple's dev portal. Create them, download them and then install them and use in Xcode.

Check if this link helps: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html